# Customize Wordpress Login aligning to center CSS

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a simple CSS problem of aligning the content to center, Basically I have a logo on the left side and the login inputs to the right side. Here is my function.php codes

```
function custom_login_css() 
{
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/login/login-styles.css" >';
}
add_action('login_head', 'custom_login_css');
```

And this is my css codes, in this codes, I used pseudocodes that generate a div with the logo and div with the content. Those are the #login before and after. As you can see I failed to put them together to center. That's my only problem, By default the #login div is set to center, but I added a div so it kinda messed up.

```
body.login {
    background: #525763;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: auto !important;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#login {
    border: 1px solid #000 !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-image: url('../login/loginbg.png');
    background-size: 350px 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-right: 10px !important;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.login h1 a {
    background-image: none;
    /*background-size: 212px 219px;
    width: 212px;
    height: 219px;*/
}
.login form {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
form#loginform {
    top: 10;
    text-align: center !important;
}
#user_login, #user_pass {
    background: #606674;
}
input#wp-submit {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 300px !important;
    background: yellow;
    color: #606674;
    border: 0px;
}
#login:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    background-image: url('../login/logo1.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 207px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 100px
}
#login:after {
    content: "Here at The Design Cereal, we aspire to share real and valuable knowledge to any individual-both new and experienced-who's looking to grow creatively in tech world especially in the advent of creative tools such as Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator. Our easy-to-understand method of writing articles hopes to simplify daunting technical requirements a designer needs to propel himself forward in his creative venture.";
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 340px
}
```

I will also include an image that is what I have in mind.
[image]

Comment: Instead making this huge code make a fiddle which will help us to see whats really going on really.

Comment: why don't you use [wp_enqueue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) ?

Comment: well this is in wordpress, I believe fiddle does not work there

Comment: wp_enqueue_style() works too. But that's not my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the input fields and logo to display block, then applying whatever CSS you need to center them.